# fetch is showing data undefined in next.js

Tags: next.js

When I am using fetch in the header.js or footer.js and include them into my layout.js I am getting value undefined. The same code is working fine on separate pages like index or about.

```
 static async getInitialProps(){
    const response =  fetch('http://localhost/coc/api/singletons/get/topbar/',{
      headers: { 'Cockpit-Token': 'ae6d9be66c544f76bf4e0676357253' }
    })
    const data= response.json();
    return { data: data }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding an `await`? Like so:

```js
const response = await fetch('http://localhost/coc/api/singletons/get/topbar/',{
      headers: { 'Cockpit-Token': 'ae6d9be66c544f76bf4e0676357253' }
    })
```